# how can fix 'noindex' detected in 'X-Robots-Tag' http header?

Tags: wordpress, sitemap, google-search-console

you can see that my site map cant be index because of this error 'noindex' detected in 'X-Robots-Tag' http header.
please help. where can i change this from noindex to index.
my site is run on wordpress.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVIB7.png)

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about WordPress development and administration can be asked on [wordpress.se]. Please delete your question here and re-ask it there.